# Connect via TTLS or via PEAP?

Tags: wireless-networking, ttls, peap

I have the option to choose either of those protocols to connect to my university WLAN.
Which should I use?
Does it matter?
What are the drawbacks of each choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use TTLS unless I had a reason not to. It's tried technology and supported across more platforms.

Here is a good (if somewhat long) overview over at O'Reilly. Be sure to read the comments to the article for more opinions.

> [A Technical Comparison of TTLS and PEAP](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/wireless/2002/10/17/peap.html)

Here is a quote from the conclusion

> Though there is not a large technical difference between the TTLS and PEAP protocols, TTLS has a number of slight advantages. In addition to a slight degree of flexibility at the protocol level, products are available now and support a much wider variety of client operating systems.